# enumitem-shortlabels: How to change the counter of items?

Tags: lists, enumerate, counters, enumitem

I use the `enumitem` package with `shortlabels`.

```
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
```

Now I've got

```
\begin{enumerate}[(L 1)]
     \item blablabla
     \item blablabla 
\end{enumerate}
```

and it goes like (L 1), (L 2) etc.

However I'd like it starts with 0. But the `setcounter{item}{-1}` doesn't work here. What to do?

Comment: Try: `\setcounter{enumi}{-1}`